# Can you use glmulti with mlogit?

Tags: r, mlogit

I am trying to determine a best-fitting model for a discrete-choice experiment. I'm using the mlogit package (Croissant, 2011). Each alternative has two alternative-specific characteristics (let's call them `V1` and `V2`), and each individual has a number of demographic characteristics (age, gender, etc). I have panel data--each individual answers ten questions

An example of the dataset:

```
ID  Ques  RES   V1  V2 Age Gender Alt
101   1   FALSE 75  75  66  1      1
101   1   TRUE  50  90  66  1      2
101   2   TRUE  10  50  66  1      1
101   2   FALSE 90  25  66  1      2
...
...
102   1   TRUE  50  90  24  0      1
102   1   FALSE 10  50  24  0      2
102   2   TRUE  75  75  24  0      1
102   2   FALSE 90  25  24  0      2
```

With the usual mlogit formulation, I would estimate my coefficients using

```
ml <- mlogit(RES ~ V1 + V2 | Age + Gender, data = data, ...)
```

What I want `glmulti` to do is determine which of the individual-specific variables need to be included--that is, I know that `V1` and `V2` need to be in the model, but I'm not sure if it should be `Age + Gender`, `Age + Gender + Age:Gender`, etc.

As far as I can tell, I would use the following command:

```
test <- glmulti(RES ~ V1 + V2 | Age + Gender, data = data, fitfunc = mlogit)
```

This, however, only seems to evaluate two models:

```
RES ~ 1
```

and

```
RES ~ 1 + V1 + V2 | Age + Gender
```

but does not evaluate any other combinations of either the individual-specific or the alternative-specific covariates. Any help would be very appreciated.